# Could not find a test logger with AssemblyQualifiedName, URI or FriendlyName ''trx'

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-devops, code-coverage, azure-pipelines

I'm having a issue with the Azure DevOps Pipeline Test Task, where I am trying to generate a .xml file from the Code Coverage Cobertura using the *trx* logger.

This is the following error that is generated: `Could not find a test logger with AssemblyQualifiedName, URI or FriendlyName ''trx'.`.

The command that I'm trying to run inside the Azure DevOps pipeline is (hiding project name for security reasons, replaced with: Mouse): `"C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" test d:\a\1\s\src\Mouse.Tests\Mouse.Tests.csproj --logger 'trx;LogFileName=coverage.cobertura.xml' --results-directory d:\a\_temp /p:CollectCoverage=true /p:CoverletOutputFormat=cobertura`.

I'm consedering downloading the xUnit logger, as I made the tests in xUnit Framework.

However, I don't understand why this command does not work in Azure DevOps Pipeline...

YAML Section:

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Run Tests
  inputs:
    command: custom
    custom: test
    arguments: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\src\Mouse.Tests\Mouse.Tests.csproj --logger 'trx;LogFileName=coverage.cobertura.xml' --results-directory $(Agent.TempDirectory) /p:CollectCoverage=true /p:CoverletOutputFormat=cobertura
```

Raw Log File:

```
2020-01-29T18:26:25.2598092Z ##[section]Starting: Run Tests
2020-01-29T18:26:25.2731938Z ==============================================================================
2020-01-29T18:26:25.2731988Z Task         : .NET Core
2020-01-29T18:26:25.2732016Z Description  : Build, test, package, or publish a dotnet application, or run a custom dotnet command
2020-01-29T18:26:25.2732058Z Version      : 2.164.0
2020-01-29T18:26:25.2732104Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2020-01-29T18:26:25.2732132Z Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/dotnet-core-cli
2020-01-29T18:26:25.2732159Z ==============================================================================
2020-01-29T18:26:25.8444463Z [command]C:\windows\system32\chcp.com 65001
2020-01-29T18:26:25.8533851Z Active code page: 65001
2020-01-29T18:26:25.8670597Z [command]"C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" test d:\a\1\s\src\Mouse.Tests\Mouse.Tests.csproj --logger 'trx;LogFileName=coverage.cobertura.xml' --results-directory d:\a\_temp /p:CollectCoverage=true /p:CoverletOutputFormat=cobertura
2020-01-29T18:26:31.0179982Z 
2020-01-29T18:26:31.1091798Z Welcome to .NET Core 3.1!
2020-01-29T18:26:31.1092168Z ---------------------
2020-01-29T18:26:31.1092336Z SDK Version: 3.1.101
2020-01-29T18:26:31.1092450Z 
2020-01-29T18:26:31.1092645Z Telemetry
2020-01-29T18:26:31.1092791Z ---------
2020-01-29T18:26:31.1093287Z The .NET Core tools collect usage data in order to help us improve your experience. The data is anonymous. It is collected by Microsoft and shared with the community. You can opt-out of telemetry by setting the DOTNET_CLI_TELEMETRY_OPTOUT environment variable to '1' or 'true' using your favorite shell.
2020-01-29T18:26:31.1093554Z 
2020-01-29T18:26:31.1093755Z Read more about .NET Core CLI Tools telemetry: https://aka.ms/dotnet-cli-telemetry
2020-01-29T18:26:31.1093858Z 
2020-01-29T18:26:31.1093970Z ----------------
2020-01-29T18:26:31.1094108Z Explore documentation: https://aka.ms/dotnet-docs
2020-01-29T18:26:31.1094382Z Report issues and find source on GitHub: https://github.com/dotnet/core
2020-01-29T18:26:31.1094484Z Find out what's new: https://aka.ms/dotnet-whats-new
2020-01-29T18:26:31.1094552Z Learn about the installed HTTPS developer cert: https://aka.ms/aspnet-core-https
2020-01-29T18:26:31.1094584Z Use 'dotnet --help' to see available commands or visit: https://aka.ms/dotnet-cli-docs
2020-01-29T18:26:31.1095022Z Write your first app: https://aka.ms/first-net-core-app
2020-01-29T18:26:31.1095076Z --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2020-01-29T18:26:43.0935889Z Test run for d:\a\1\s\src\Mouse.Tests\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\Mouse.Tests.dll(.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1)
2020-01-29T18:26:43.4592444Z Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 16.3.0
2020-01-29T18:26:43.4592843Z Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
2020-01-29T18:26:43.4593019Z 
2020-01-29T18:26:43.9392318Z Starting test execution, please wait...
2020-01-29T18:26:44.0028395Z Could not find a test logger with AssemblyQualifiedName, URI or FriendlyName ''trx'.
2020-01-29T18:26:44.0527365Z ##[error]Error: The process 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe' failed with exit code 1
2020-01-29T18:26:44.0539503Z Info: Azure Pipelines hosted agents have been updated to contain .Net Core 3.x SDK/Runtime along with 2.2 & 2.1. Unless you have locked down a SDK version for your project(s), 3.x SDK might be picked up which might have breaking behavior as compared to previous versions. 
2020-01-29T18:26:44.0539612Z Some commonly encountered changes are: 
2020-01-29T18:26:44.0539670Z If you're using `Publish` command with -o or --Output argument, you will see that the output folder is now being created at root directory rather than Project File's directory. To learn about more such changes and troubleshoot, refer here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/dotnet-core-cli?view=azure-devops#troubleshooting
2020-01-29T18:26:44.0539944Z ##[error]Dotnet command failed with non-zero exit code on the following projects : 
2020-01-29T18:26:44.0557864Z ##[section]Finishing: Run Tests
```

Comment: How about the result when you use the command line on your local without Azure devops?

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT It runs smoothly, without any error and generates the XML file.

Comment: If it works on your local but not with Azure devops, this issue should be more related to the EVN. What is your .net core version of your project? You could try to add `Use .NET Core` task to set the .nte core version when you use the hosted agent.

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT It's the .NET Core 3.1. The version it is using is the same from the project, don't have issues with that. Could you please say what is the EVN? Environment? Should I open an issue in Azure Pipeline Tasks GitHub?